# How is the filter response affected by the sampling rate?

Tags: filter, sampling

At this filter, the sampling frequency is changing the output bode plot.

I have never thought this before. What is the explanation of this?

edit: will be updated soon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A higher sampling frequency means more bandwidth below the nyquist point (the right hand end of the X-axis).

> *So can we say it doesn't change the transfer function correct?*

As your sampling rate approaches the cut-off frequency then the characteristic is highly affected due to a thing called frequency warping.

> *I see, but if the sampling rate is beyond the Nyquist freq., the only
> thing changes in the plot is the curve-fitting not the transfer
> function I guess?*

The sampling rate is always twice the nyquist frequency. It defines the nyquist frequency. As the cut-off frequency gets closer to the nyquist frequency the filter's roll-off response is highly concentrated into the little space between cut-off and nyquist with 100 % (total) attenuation at the nyquist frequency. This is the price to pay for using digital filters.

- The very act of sampling produces a filter; if you sample at twice the frequency of the input waveform you will get zero effective output i.e. sampling is a notch filter.
- If your input is the same frequency as the sampling frequency then what do you get that makes any sense - i.e. you will sample at the same point on the waveform every time and get a DC value.

So, when you make a digital filter to behave in a butterworth response (for example) you also get for free, another response superimposed on top and, as you bring nyquist frequency and desired cut-off frequency closer you get a bit of a mess.

Comment: So can we say it doesn't change the transfer function correct?

Comment: As your sampling rate approaches the cut-off frequency then the characteristic is highly affected due to a thing called frequency warping.

Comment: I see, but if the sampling rate is beyond the Nyquist freq., the only thing changes in the plot is the curve-fitting not the transfer function I guess?

Comment: The sampling rate is always twice the nyquist frequency. It defines the nyquist frequency. As the cut-off frequency gets closer to the nyquist frequency the filter's roll-off response is highly concentrated into the little space between cut-off and nyquist with 100 % (total) attenuation at the nyquist frequency. This is the price to pay for using digital filters.

Answer (score 1):

It is not changing the filter cut-off frequency.
However, the x axis is from `0` to `fs/2`. As you vary the sampling frequency the x axis limits effectively change and the cut off frequency location within the graph changes.

> It doesn't change the transfer function ?

It does. The filter coefficients as well as the response. Below is my result in Octave software for a first order low pass filter

```matlab
   1
 -----
 s + 1


c2d(..., 0.1, 'tustin')

 0.04762 z + 0.04762
 -------------------
     z - 0.9048

Sampling time: 0.1 s



c2d(..., 0.05, 'tustin')

 0.02439 z + 0.02439
 -------------------
     z - 0.9512
Sampling time: 0.05 s
```

[image: bodeplot]

Even though the cut off frequency is the same, the response is different especially at high frequencies. As mentioned in the other answer,the warping effects which are significant near the Nyquist frequency occur differently for filters of different sampling frequency.

Comment: it doesn't change the transfer function correct?

Comment: It kind of does. The filter with sampling frequency 100 Hz would have a transfer function with frequency ranging from 0 to 50 Hz while another filter with sampling frequency 500 Hz would have its transfer function with frequency ranging from 0 to 250 Hz. So yeah, the transfer functions will be different even if cut off frequencies are the same.