# Bilinear transformation: why does it cause a deformation on my filter

Tags: digital-filter

So I'm designing a Butterworth 4th order highpass digital filter. I developed all my equations (I can put them here if it is relevant) and arrived to this graphs for the frequency response. In red there is the original analog filter and in blue the digital filter.

[image]

[image]

Can someone please help me understand why I'm observing these differences? I used the bilinear transformation which I know adds up zeros to the transfer function, but I can't understand why these zeros seem to add a 0.4 dB error in the edge frequency of the filter (3000 Hz) and it seems to shift the phase response to the left. Can anyone clarify this to me? Thank you!

Comment: That's a high pass response and you mentioned a low pass filter.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I'm designing a lot of the filters at the same time these past few days. Will fix it, thank you!

Comment: That's what bilinear transform does. It warps f=inf to f=fs, and all lower frequencies down a bit to match, so frequency errors increase as you get closer to fs/2. There are approaches to compensate for this frequency warping; probably in the next chapter of whatever you're reading.

Comment: [How is the filter response affected by the sampling rate?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/534198/how-is-the-filter-response-affected-by-the-sampling-rate/534200#5342000).